# Will moving a table/partition to a different tablespace interrupt queries accessing said table/partition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

As the title says: will moving (without renaming) a table/partition while it's being accessed have negative consequences on any queries accessing it?

For example, say there's a long-running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table`.
If I were to `ALTER TABLE some_table MOVE TABLESPACE some_other_tablespace`, would the `SELECT` fail?
Would it complete, but have incorrect results?  Maybe something else entirely?

The only info I could find was that moving the table to a different tablespace would require rebuilding the indices under certain circumstances, but none made mention of what happens to any active queries.

Comment: On a side note, would the consequences be different for moving a single partition vs moving an entire (un-partitioned) table?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables006.htm#i1106606 - "The ALTER TABLE...MOVE statement does not permit DML against the table while the statement is executing. " I believe the move won't even start in normal circumstances if there's activity on the table. Direct path operations might do less fun stuff. (IOTs can be moved online, possibly with some restrictions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might fail with `ORA-08103: object no longer exists`.

In Oracle, readers and writers do not block each other.  Which means DML and queries will not interfere with each other, excluding a few weird cases like running out of UNDO space.  But moving a tablespace, or any type of ALTER or other DDL statement, is not a normal write.  The multiversion concurrency control model breaks down when you run DDL, at least for the involved objects, and weird things start to happen.

Testing a large move is difficult, but you can reproduce these errors by looping through a lot of small alters and queries.  In case you think this is only a theoretical issue, I have seen these errors occur in real-life, on a production database.

Warning: infinite loops below since I can't predict how long it will take to reproduce this error.  But it usually only takes me tens of seconds.

```
--Create sample table.
drop table test1 purge;
create table test1(a number, b number)
partition by list(a) (partition p1 values(1), partition p2 values(2))
nologging tablespace users;

--Session 1
begin
  loop
    execute immediate '
      insert /*+ append */ into test1 select mod(level,2)+1, level
      from dual connect by level <= 100000';
    commit;
    execute immediate 'alter table test1 move partition p1 tablespace users';
  end loop;
end;
/       

--Session 2: Read from moved partition
declare
  v_count number;
begin
  loop
    select count(*) into v_count from test1 where a = 1;
  end loop;
end;
/

--Session 3: Read from unmoved partition
declare
  v_count number;
begin
  loop
    select count(*) into v_count from test1 where a = 2;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Session 2 will eventually die with:

```
ORA-08103: object no longer exists
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Session 3 will not fail, it is not querying an altered partition.  Each partition has its own segment, and is a separate object that can potentially "no longer exist".

Comment: Thanks much for your response.  It's not the answer I was hoping for, but it's a good answer nonetheless.  On a site note: will similar errors likely occur if I were to move a partition of a table?

Comment: @GigaWatt I believe so, but I'm not yet able to reproduce this error when I use partitioning.  My simple example doesn't throw an error - perhaps because partitioning caches the data differently?  I'll try to reproduce the error and get back to you later.

Comment: @GigaWatt I updated my answer with a more specific partition example.  Both partitioned and non-partitioned can fail.  For some reason I don't understand, the partitioned version tends to take much longer to fail.  But I wouldn't rely on that behavior, it might just be bad luck in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

A partition move WILL cause DML to fail if it is accessing the parition.

I just proved it :-/.

I was doing a large delete and tried to move a partition (alter table move partition).
The error I received was:
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P004ORA-08103: object no longer exists