# ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P011

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle11gr2, oracle11gr1

I have stored procedure, which has parallel queries and hints. Frequently we are getting error details as below.

> An error occurred executing the stored procedure.
>   TM_6159 [4294965496] [
>   ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P011, instance dbssd0011:proddb1 (1)
>   ORA-08103: object no longer exists
>   ORA-06512: at "PROD1.PKG_PTS", line 5068
>   ORA-06512: at line 2
>   Database driver error...
>   Function Name : ExecuteSP
>   Oracle Fatal Error
>   Database driver error...
>   Function Name : ExecuteSP
>   Oracle Fatal Error]**

After rerun it got succeeded, we are getting this error frequently every alternate day. We are in Oracle 10g.

Please share your inputs on the same.

Regards,
Shamsheer

Comment: Without seeing, the code, who knows?  Are you using any temp tables?

Comment: its has more than 5000 lines of code, the line number it is showing is end of the procedure, yes..few temp tables using in procedure.

Comment: "ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P011" Is it any generic error for parallel processing in oracle 10g.

Comment: But,  "ORA-08103: object no longer exists" is specific.  Have you tried turning on tracing and looking at the resulting output?

Comment: But object existed, after rerun its succeeded. Please let me know trace files will helpus here to find the root cause.

Comment: google "oracle trace file" and read the docs.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15531881/409172).  There's probably some code performing DDL on one of the underlying objects while it's being read.  If that's the case, let me know and I'll close this as a duplicate.